# How do I remove space between text and table?

Tags: php, html, css

I have this table and the more rows I add to the table the more space is formed between the table and the text above the table.

```
$qq=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM piatto");
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Descrizione</th>
<th>Tempo</th>``
<th>Prezzo</th>
<th>quantita</th>
</tr>";

while($cicle=mysql_fetch_array($qq)){ 

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".  $cicle['id']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".  $cicle['titolo']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".  $cicle['descrizione']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".  $cicle['tempo_preparazione']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".  $cicle['prezzo']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".  $cicle['quantita']."</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<br />";  

}    
echo "</table>" ;
echo"<br />";`enter code here`
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What you mean space added between?

Comment: Look at your HTML source and compare it with what you have for your source code. This should be a no brainer.

Comment: Though your answer is likely unrelated, I'd like to point out that `<br />` is not acceptable within a `<table>` unless it's in a `<td>`. That being said, your code here has no "text before the table". We can't really debug your issue without more information.

Comment: First of all, look into Pdo for db queries. It is safer to use. Secondly, remove adding br at the end of the while loop. You should not need to put a linebreak between table rows. Add an empty row or increase the border-bottom of the row in terms of css.

Comment: Ashrat, what is the purpose of the `echo "<br />";` after the `echo "</tr>";`?

Comment: @Santi I think it's likely _not_ unrelated.

Comment: SOLVED! it was that <br /> ...i'm really new in html programming and i 
and I have not thought of that <br /> could influence the space above the table. thank you by the way .

Comment: @Don'tPanic Just like I said... it's completely related and 100% the cause of the issue! Haha, good call. I'm realizing now that a smart browser may move that `<br>` to just before the `<table>`, thus pushing it down.

Comment: @Santi I figured that's what you meant. ;)

Answer (score 2):

What is the reason for the `<br />` inside the table? As it's not wrapped in a `<td>` it won't be included as part of the table and will actually display above the table instead. As the `<br />` is part of your while loop the more rows you have the more breaks you'll have above the table.

If you're wanting to increase spacing between rows use either CSS or just include an empty table row.